# Using regex to separate items

Tags: php, regex, wordpress

I have a piece of code that I use to extract my WordPress categories. It's like this:

```
<?php foreach ($terms as $term) { echo $term->slug ;} ?>
```

That code will generate a list of categories like this:

```
BrazilItalyThailand
```

But I need the output to be like this:

```
"Brazil","Italy","Thailand"
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
    foreach($terms as $term) 
    {
        $cats[] = $term->slug;
    }
    $str = '"'.implode('","', array_unique($cats)).'"';
?>
```

no need of regex!

Comment: Its almost there. However when I echo $str, it's duplicating all the items.

Comment: @Daniel would you give the current output?

Comment: this foreach generates the <li> from a list. So, for each list item, the code increment. For example. The first <li> the output is "italy","brazil". The last element of the list the output is "italy","brazil","italy","thailand","italy","brazil","thailand","italy","brazil","italy"

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php 
foreach ($terms as $term) { 
   echo '"' . $term->slug . '",';
} 
?>
```

Comment: There will be a **,** at the end of **"Thailand"**.

Comment: That didn't produce the right outputp "brazil',"italy',"thailand',

Comment: Indeed, implode might be better.